# Alert email in TFS and power tools

Tags: email, tfs, notifications

I have a problem with TFS and email notifications.
I can not receive any emails from TFS server for work item tracking.
I correctly have configured web.config in ...\Web Services\Services in TFS server and I am using power tools for alert.
But when I set an alert to notify me for an item, any event haven't happened yet.
I have checked event viewer in TFS server but didn't have any information, error or warning for my alert(email).  If I change `emailNotificationFromAddress` in web.config, after Team Foundation Core Web Service Application restart a warning happens including this message:

```
"TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 11/18/2009 1:38:59 PM
Machine: TFS
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/1520656728/Root/Services-6-129030251360070129
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 5676
  Thread Id: 3292
  Account name: RPK\TFSService

Detailed Message: TF50282: Could not connect to the following e-mail server: mail.rpk.ir 
    Error message: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, String from)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebServiceNotification.SendOneEmail(Boolean plaintext, String to)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp."
```

and after that, It hadn't happened any event for any alerts!

Comment: Are you trying to send mail from an account in a different domain? Many SMTP servers will block this.

Comment: I think yes.but I don't know different domain ?what does it mean in this?
I use exchange server as mail server.can u explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but most TFS problems I've encountered boil down to user privileges.

Check which user account TFS is using (it's likely to be TFSSERVICE or TFSREPORTS, and almost certainly won't be your administrator login). Make sure this user account has access to the mail server you're using.

Comment: Is it different between Active Directory Users and TFS users?
I guess your say that:I shoukd use something like TFSSERVICE or TFSREPORTS for emailNotificationFromAddress ?
and how can I check which user account TFS user account is using? :(
any event didn't log in event viewer.

Comment: Usually you set up TFS with two user accounts on the server (the  above are the default names, so if you didn't change them when installing, that's probably what you're using). These are local user accounts on the server. The powertools "best practces analyser" may help you determine which accounts you have, and if you're lucky it may also be able to detect the problem and give you help in resolving it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx

Comment: how can I get powertools "best practces analyser"? I knew that To launch the Best Practices Analyzer for Team Foundation Server , click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools, point to Microsoft Visual Studio Team System Best Practices Analyzer, and then click TfsBpa.exe but I cann't find it. I downloaded Power Tools from this link : microsoft.com/downloads/… but there is not TfsBpa.exe!! Is it something wrong?

Comment: It should be there somewhere - I had trouble finding one or two of these tools until I just did a search on my drive for the filename.

Comment: I search All drives but I can not find it!
another problem that I have:
my account in AD is not user in TFS.
It have been change to another user in my computer.
but when log in by another computer in domain to TFS my user is true.
do u have any idea about this problem?

Comment: BPA is definitely included in the power tools, from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en
(Are you searching within the user account that installed the tools? The files may not be visible to other users)

Comment: Your personal account should be irrelevant to the operation of TFS - IIRC it runs under about 3 different accounts (TFSSERVICE, TFSREPORTS, and some stuff runs on the built in Network service account). However, for all the parts of TFS to connect up and work properly, these accounts all need to have the right permissions, as do the SQL Server logins that they use. There are a number of logs written by different systems, so if you can track the right ones down and decipher them, they may give you a clue. But unless you're an expert, this can be difficult and painful to troubleshoot!

Comment: If you're running exchange server, then try configuring it (ES) to allow access by the TFSSERVICE account (or have the TFSSERVICE account as a known user. This is just a guess as I didn't set up the exchange server on our system, so don't know what needed to be done to get it working for email reports. But it sounds like all you need is for the TFSSERVICE or TFSREPORTS user to have access to exchange server)

Comment: with this account I can not recive any email from TFS alert.
I confused! :((
plz help me.
how can i cofig SMPT server to allow anonymous senders to send e-mail??

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with SMTP server configuration. It's always "just worked" for me, so I've never had the need to delve any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using an account with minimal rights on exchange server, but that do have the 'send as' rights. Alternatively you can allow anonymous send on your exchange server smtp connector ONLY from the ip address of the TFS.